# how to scroll internet browser web page without sendkeys in vbscript

Tags: scroll, vbscript, automation, sendkeys

I need to scroll my web page without using send keys in vb script. Please let any help.I trying to googling , but i didn't get any code.how to scroll internet browser web page without sendkeys in vbscript

Comment: you can use [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) on an element...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) which is a Firefox plugin to automate web browsers.

Try the following in an iMacros script:

```
url goto=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,20000)
```

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help :) Remember to mark the solution that solved your problem as the accepted answer, to benefit the entire stack overflow community :)